# Making text commands such as coloring a text

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, text, jtextarea

I want to make a method that would sort of analyze a `String` and whenever a text command (`/r` to turn the text red for example) is found, the text command is not shown and its applied to the text following the command.

For example, a string:

```
"Hello /rworl/bd"
```

The output would be as follows:

```
"Hello world"
```

but `"Hello worl"` would be in red text and the final `d` would be in blue. I know how to change the text color, make it bold etc.

What is a good way to select the text after a command?

Comment: If your regex isn't working, then include that and we can offer a suggestion.

Comment: Sorry, JTextArea. 

I rarelly use regex so i first thought about converting the string into an array and use a for-loop but theres probably a much easier way which is why i'm posting here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I couldn't find a good way to use multiple fonts on a JTextArea but here it is working with a label and html. When you type in the letters will be black. If you press '/' it will be waiting for the text character to decide the colour. If you then press 'r' the font for the following letters will be set to red, 'b' for blue.

```
public class TextColour implements KeyListener {
    JLabel label;
    String red = "<font color='FF0000'>";
    String blue = "<font color='0000FF'>";
    String text = "";
    boolean colour = false;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TextColour();

    }

    public TextColour() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        JTextArea area = new JTextArea();

        area.addKeyListener(this);
        label = new JLabel();

        frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 100));
        frame.getContentPane().add(area);
        frame.getContentPane().add(label);

        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent key) {
        char letter = key.getKeyChar();
        if (colour) {
            if (letter == 'r') {
                text += red;
            } else if (letter == 'b') {
                text += blue;
            }
            colour = false;
        } else if (letter == '/') {
            colour = true;
        } else {
            text += key.getKeyChar();
        }
        label.setText("<html>" + text + "</html>");
    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent arg0) {
    }

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent arg0) {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`JTextArea` is a component for plain text.  One single font face, style & size, & one foreground and background color can be set.  For formatted **uneditable** text, use a `JLabel` as suggested by @Glitch.  For **editable** text, use components like `JEditorPane` or `JTextPane`.

See the [How to Use Editor Panes and Text Panes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/editorpane.html) section of the tutorial for: further details, working code ..& cute screen-shots. :)

[image]